# Почему каждое новое развертывание проекта на WildFly продолжает работать не заменяя предыдущую версию?

Tags: java, maven, развертывание, wildfly, jboss

На сервере WildFly уже крутятся приложения (с аннотацией @Schedule). Хотел сделать свое, скопировав скелет.

После нескольких деплоев проекта (с помощью mvn clean install wildfly:deploy), заметил, что предыдущие версии не заменяются. То есть в интерфейсе WildFly видно только одно развертывание, а по факту работают все предыдущие деплои.

Пробовал исправить командой redeploy - не помогает.
Помогает только перезагрузка WildFly - начинает работает только последнее развертывание.

Для всех других приложений (написанных до меня) команда wildfly:deploy работает нормально, каждый раз заменяя предыдущую версию.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

UPD: После удаления приложения через интерфейс WildFly, оно все так же продолжает работать...

Comment: Включите больше деталей.

Comment: @RomanC можете подсказать, про какие моменты стоит дополнить?